# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence with spring, glassfish, hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to develop a simple application using JavaEE, Spring, Glassfish 4, jpa (hibernate) and mysql. 
but im having problems with the Hibernate Persistence class.

I get the following exception:

```
2014-09-05T14:08:53.651-0300|Grave: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
...
```

For other questions are resolved by adding dependencies to pom.xml. But I'm trying to fix it since a few days ago, and I always receive the same error.

here its the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
<artifactId>springapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springapp</finalName>
</build>
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

my applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/stu_infoPU" />  
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />  


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.service" />
</beans>
```

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="stu_infoPU" transaction-type="JTA">  
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
        <!--JNDIJDBC -->  
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/springapp</jta-data-source>  
        <properties>  
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>  
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>  
        </properties>  
    </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

and this is an example of using persistence

```
@Repository(value = "productDao")
public class JPAProductDao implements ProductDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return em.createQuery("select p from Product p order by p.id").getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        em.merge(prod);
    }

}
```

Comment: That class is inside hibernate-entitymanager, that you have in your pom. How do you launch the application?

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite, Run As/Run on Server/GlassFish ...

Comment: Change your provider in persistence.xml to "<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>" and see if it works. Also refer "http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4.3/Hibernate-4.3-and-JPA-2.1-Example.shtml" for more details.

Comment: not work: Exception while preparing the app: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider. A good tutorial with an example that works I think it would be very useful.